# Bmx tire hole. Won't pump up!

Tags: bmx, bike-setup

So I found a small thorn in my tire. It did make a hole in my tube so I replaced it after trying many solutions. My question: I'm wondering if because there is a hole in the tire but not the tube, why won't my tire fill with air?

Answer (score 2):

Take the tube out and find out why its leaking. A picture or description of the tube damage may help diagnosis.

A variety of things could have caused this:

- Something else stuck in the tire which damaged the tube
- Pinching the tube between the rim and the tire
- Damage at the valve
- A bad tube
- A spoke coming through and punching the tube
- Damaged Rim Tape
- Etc.

If there is an appreciable hole or damage in the tire, it won't protect the tube and you need a new tire.

Recommended reading: [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/flats.html)

Comment: If there is a "medium sized" hole in the tube -- too large to permit simple tube replacement but small enough that the tire's integrity is not threatened -- then a "boot" inside the tire can be use.